# How does the Google Maps Java API determine the supported TLS protocols?

Tags: java, google-maps, tls1.2

I can successfully run the example Google Maps code in a standalone Java 8 project:

```
            GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey("API_KEY_HERE")
                .build();
            GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
                "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(results[0].addressComponents));
```

However, if I run it within my existing application, I see:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true), ConnectionSpec()], supported protocols=[TLSv1]
```

indicating that it thinks that only TLSv1 is available. But if I create an SSLSocket in the same file:

```
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket("www.verisign.com", 443);
            String[] protocols = sslSocket.getEnabledProtocols();
```

I see that TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 are all available. How does Google Maps source its TLS versions and how do I tell it to use TLS 1.2?

Comment: What version of the api are you using?

Comment: Google Maps version 0.10.1

Answer (score 0):

its looks like some version issue you can try with different version of TLS and also Maps api